# The act of identifying somone's group by their vocabulary

Tags: ideology, terminology

I heard this once before, but I forgot the word for it. I've already tried to searched it on google but I could not find anything useful.

"Tribalism" is a new word to express the political bubbles people are living in. And you can easily identify someone's "bubble" by their vocabulary. For example, left-wing people might say things like "oppression, capitalist pigs, racist, homophobic" while right-wing people usually don't.

**I would like to know the name of this act. The act of identifying someone's group by their vocabulary.**

Comment: The vocabulary / language itself is called a _sociolect_, although that doesn't necessarily refer to one's political point of view.

Comment: There may be an actuary word for classification, but I kinda doubt they use a new word for each way of making a classification. Email data miners certainly use techniques like this to sort people, and may have a special word for political sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One notable term is [Shibboleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth)

> A shibboleth is either a saying that people repeatedly cite that is
>   wrong (or thought to be wrong by some), or a word or custom whose
>   variations in pronunciation or style distinguish members of ingroups
>   from those of outgroups, with an implicit value judgment based on
>   familiarity with the shibboleth.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the word I've been looking for. Like I said, I heard it before, but I had forget it and did not remember where I first saw it. Shibboleth!